# Why isnt my +-/x functions work while my sine cosine and tangent work

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

float sine(float  x);
float cosine(float x);
float tangent(float x);

int main()
{
    int n;
    float x, y, answer;
    printf("Welcome to Guru\'s Scientific Calculator.");
    Sleep(3000);
    system("cls");
    Sleep(500);
    printf("Wait, while we gather required\ndatabases for the application to\nfunction properly!\n\n");
    Sleep(7500);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1.sin\n2.cos\n3.tan\n4.Addition\n5.Subtraction\n6.Division\n7.Multipication\n\nYour input: ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    if (n<3 && n>0)
    {
        printf("\n What is x?\nYour input: ");
        scanf("%f",&x);
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : answer = sine(x);       break;
            case 2 : answer = cosine(x);     break;
            case 3 : answer = tangent(x);    break;
        }
    }
    if (n<7 && n>3){
        printf("What is x and y?\nYour inputs: ");
        scanf("%f , %f", x, y);
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : answer = (x + y);       break;
            case 2 : answer = (x - y);       break;
            case 3 : answer = (x / y);       break;
            case 4 : answer = (x * y);       break;
        }
    }
    if (n>0 && n<8)
        printf("%f",answer);
    else
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
    return 0;
}

float sine(float x)
{
    return (sin (x*PI/180));
}

float cosine(float x)
{
    return (cos (x*PI/180));
}

float tangent(float x)
{
    return (tan(x*PI/180));
}
```

the sin, cos, tan functions are still able to work. Not my addition, subtraction, multipication, and division. Why? what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Compare the `scanf` lines. Also, you should check the return value of `scanf` in all places.

Comment: Non-formatting text in a `scanf` string must be matched literally. If you have a comma in the format string, then you must enter a comma as input at that position. The only special non-format character is space, which matches zero or more of any white-space character.

Comment: @kaylum like i am abke to input for the sin and all, but whin i click i want to do addiiton or others, it dosent ask for input but just goes and print 0 and leaves

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to include the *full* and *complete* input and output to your program, copy-pasted as text without any modifications.

Comment: You're checking that `n` is between 3 and 7, which allows 4, 5, or 6, but the switch statement is looking for 1 thru 4.

Comment: And a possible hint about your problem: What happens if the user inputs `3` in the menu? Why don't you have a big `switch` statement for *all* menu input? There's no need to split it up.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if there was a big switch statement, but the first part with cos tan sin just need one user input, while the others have 2. how will it work?

Comment: Ah that's true, but you still need to look over your logic and the values. I also recommend that you learn to create and use functions, it will make your code easier to read and understand.

Comment: regarding: ` scanf("%f , %f", x, y);`  The variable parameters MUST be pointers to the variables.  Suggest: ` scanf( "%f , %f",  &x, &y );`  BTW: should always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current statement, any returned value other than 2 indicates an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `if (n<3 && n>0)`  This is excluding `3` which is needed for the `tan` selection.  Suggest: `if (n<=3 && n>0)`

Comment: The syntax for `sin()`:   `double sin(double x)` Note the passed in parameter AND the returned value have type `double`, not `float`.  Similar considerations exist for `cos()` and `tan()`  Also, those values `180` should be `180.0` (a double) rather than `180` (an integer)

Comment: regarding: `if (n<7 && n>3){
        printf("What is x and y?\nYour inputs: ");
        scanf("%f , %f", x, y);
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : answer = (x + y);       break;
            case 2 : answer = (x - y);       break;
            case 3 : answer = (x / y);       break;
            case 4 : answer = (x * y);       break;
        }
    }`   the value 'n' has valid values of 4...7, Not 1...4

Comment: regarding: `if (n<7 && n>3){`  This allows for values 4,5,6 BUT the switch statement is looking for 4 values.  Perhaps you meant: `if( n <= 7 && n > 3 )`

Comment: regarding: `if (n>0 && n<8)
        printf("%f",answer);
    else
        printf("Wrong input.\n");`  This 'validating' of the user input is far far removed from where the value is actually input by the user.  This is a very poor programming practice.  Suggest the validating of the user input be immediately after the call to `scanf()` that inputs that selection.  BTW:  since the input can only be a single character, suggest calling `getchar()` (which returns an `int`) rather than a call to `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. incorporates the comments to the question
4. does not perform error checking for the functions: `scanf()` and `system()`. which you should add the error checking for robust code
5. notice the use of 'concatenation' of strings in the calls to `printf()` to enable honoring the right margin (for printing and such)
6. notice the use of `double` to match the syntax for the functions defined in `math.h`
7. corrected the spelling for `multiplication`
8. used a `do...while` loop to input the desired selection value and verify its' validity
9. used a call to `getchar()` to input the desired selection value
10. checks for and avoids division by 0.0

caveat: there is 'PI' value defined in the header file `math.h`  as: `#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

double sine   ( double x );
double cosine ( double x );
double tangent( double x );

int main( void )
{
    int n;
    double x;
    double y;
    double answer;

    printf("Welcome to Guru\'s Scientific Calculator.");

    Sleep(3000);
    system("cls");
    Sleep(500);
    printf("Wait, while we gather required\n"
           "databases for the application to\n"
           "function properly!\n\n");
    Sleep(7500);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    do
    {
        printf("What do you want to do?\n"
               "1.sin\n"
               "2.cos\n"
               "3.tan\n"
               "4.Addition\n"
               "5.Subtraction\n"
               "6.Division\n"
               "7.Multiplication\n"
               "\nYour input: ");
        n = getchar();
    } while( 1 > n || n > 8 );

    if ( n < 4 )
    {
        printf("\n What is x?\n"
               "Your input: ");
        scanf("%lf",&x);

        switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : 
                answer = sine(x);       
                break;

            case 2 : 
                answer = cosine(x);     
                break;

            case 3 : 
                answer = tangent(x);    
                break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        printf("What is x and y?\n"
               "Your inputs: ");
        scanf("%lf , %lf", &x, &y);
        switch (n)
        {
            case 4 : 
                answer = (x + y);       
                break;

            case 5 : 
                answer = (x - y);       
                break;

            case 6 : 
                if( y == 0.0 )
                {
                    printf( "%s\n", 
                       "cannot perform division by 0" ); 
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                answer = (x / y);       
                break;

            case 7 : 
                answer = (x * y);       
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("%lf",answer);

    return 0;
}

double sine( double x )
{
    return (sin (x*PI/180.0));
}

double cosine( double x )
{
    return (cos (x*PI/180.0));
}

double tangent( double x )
{
    return (tan(x*PI/180.0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the second case block, your `case` statements looks for 1 to 4:

```
if (n<7 && n>3){
    printf("What is x and y?\nYour inputs: ");
    scanf("%f , %f", x, y);
    switch (n)
    {
        case 1 : answer = (x + y);       break;
        case 2 : answer = (x - y);       break;
        case 3 : answer = (x / y);       break;
        case 4 : answer = (x * y);       break;
    }
}
```

But the code you are reading is from 4 to 7. You need to check for the proper cases. Also, check for `n<8`, because 7 is not smaller than 7; and correct the `scanf`:

```
if (n<8 && n>3){
    printf("What is x and y?\nYour inputs: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
    switch (n)
    {
        case 4 : answer = (x + y);       break;
        case 5 : answer = (x - y);       break;
        case 6 : answer = (x / y);       break;
        case 7 : answer = (x * y);       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%f , %f", x, y);` This just repeats (one of) OP's mistakes.

Comment: so it should be scanf("%f %f", x, y); isit?

Comment: @Guru You have `scanf("%f",&x);` in the part that works. Compare the two.

Comment: You have to use `&`

Comment: @Guru It can be `scanf("%f%f", &x, &y)` or `scanf("%f ,%f", &x, &y)`, but if you put the comma in the `scanf` format string, then you need to type the comma between the numbers, e.g. `3.4,5.6`

Comment: oh. ok thanks community. i can rely on you guys 100 percent sia. Awesome

Comment: If `n` is `3` it will just fall through without executing the code for tangent.